# Max Length Substring without any repeating character

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, set

Given a String, find the length of longest substring without any repeating character.

```
Example 1:

Input: s = ”abcabcbb”

Output: 3

Explanation: The answer is abc with length of 3.

Example 2:

Input: s = ”bbbbb”

Output: 1

Explanation: The answer is b with length of 1 units.
```

My solution works, but it isn't optimised. How can this be done in `O(n)` time?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int solve(string str) {

  if(str.size()==0)
      return 0;
  int maxans = INT_MIN;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) // outer loop for traversing the string
  {
    unordered_set < int > set;
    for (int j = i; j < str.length(); j++) // nested loop for getting different string starting with str[i]
    {
      if (set.find(str[j]) != set.end()) // if element if found so mark it as ans and break from the loop
      {
        maxans = max(maxans, j - i);
        break;
      }
      set.insert(str[j]);
    }
  }
  return maxans;
}

int main() {
  string str = "abcsabcds";
  cout << "The length of the longest substring without repeating characters is " << 
  solve(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the set for elements of the current longest subchain, and test if the new char is inside or not  this set.

Answer (score 1):

Use a two pointer approach along with a hashmap here.

1. Initialise two pointers `i = 0, j = 0` (`i` and `j` denote the left and right boundary of the current substring)
2. If the `j-th` character is not in the map, we can extend the substring. Add the `j-th` char to the map and increment `j`.
3. If the `j-th` character is in the map, we can not extend the substring without removing the earlier occurrence of the character. Remove the `i-th` char from the map and increment `i`.
4. Repeat this while `j < length of string`

This will have a time and space complexity of `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // 1
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    // 2
    std::vector<int> lut(127, -1);
    int i, beg{ 0 }, len_curr{ 0 }, len_ans{ 0 };
    for (i = 0; i != s.size(); ++i) {
        if (lut[s[i]] == -1 || lut[s[i]] < beg) {
            ++len_curr;
        }
        else {
            if (len_curr > len_ans) {
                len_ans = len_curr;
            }
            beg = lut[s[i]] + 1;
            len_curr = i - lut[s[i]];
        }
        lut[s[i]] = i;
    }
    if (len_curr > len_ans) {
        len_ans = len_curr;
    }
    // 3
    std::cout << len_ans << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

In // 1 you:

Define and read your string s.

In // 2 you:

Define your look up table lut, which is a vector of int and consists of 127 buckets each initialized with -1. As per [this](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sjost/it212/documents/ascii-pr.htm) article there are 95 printable ASCII characters numbered 32 to 126 hence we allocated 127 buckets. lut[ch] is the position in s where you found the character ch for the last time.
Define i (index variable for s), beg (the position in s where your current substring begin at), len_curr (the length of your current substring), len_ans (the length you are looking for).

Loop through s. If you have never found the character s[i] before **OR** you have found it but at a position **BEFORE** beg (It belonged to some previous substring in s) you increment len_curr. Otherwise you have a repeating character ! You compare len_curr against len_ans and If needed you assign. Your new beg will be the position **AFTER** the one you found your repeating character for the last time at. Your new len_curr will be the difference between your current position in s and the position that you found your repeating character for the last time at.

You assign i to lut[s[i]] which means that you found the character s[i] for the last time at position i.

You repeat the If clause when you fall through the loop because your longest substring can be **IN** the end of s.

In // 3 you:

Print len_ans.